# Constructing a URL based on existing variables

Tags: php

I'm a bit of a PHP newbie, and I'm trying to do what I believe is quite a complicated operation on a website. So I need your help :)

What I want to do is request a specific page for each client, the only URL variables involved are at the end, as normal.

Basically my variables have been set previously in the script, what I want to say is;
The URL is `http://site.com/index.php?image=$clientnumber`  Somehow.

if you guys could give me some insight on how to do this, that would be great!

Comment: Is your question about "constructing an URL" or about "how to generate a unique client number"?

Comment: are you setting those variables in the same (php-)script? or are they transfered via a form submit? because most likely you want to have a print_r() look in either $_POST or $_GET

Comment: It would be helpful to extend your question on what it is you exactly want as @nkr commented, that said, the relevant parts of the source code on what the situation is now, might be a good start to get some answers ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [sprintf function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) to do this:

```
$url = sprintf('http://site.com/index.php?image=%s', $clientnumber);
```

Answer (score 1):

[PHP String Operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php)

```
$new_url = "http://site.com/index.php?image=$clientnumber";
```

or

```
$new_url = 'http://site.com/index.php?image=' . $clientnumber;
```

Comment: The variable is constant, it comes from a database earlier in the script, I basically need the URL to use in an image frame. It has authentication variables too, but I didn't want to complicate the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
$data = array('foo'=>'bar',
              'baz'=>'boom',
              'cow'=>'milk',
              'php'=>'hypertext processor');

echo http_build_query($data) . "\n";
```

Results in:

> foo=bar&baz=boom&cow=milk&php=hypertext+processor

For your needs:

```
$data = array('image'=> $clientnumber);
echo 'index.php?' . $data;
```

Will give you:

> index.php?image=878787283

Comment: That seems like a more graceful solution. For the sake of simplicity I didn't say I was also adding $login and $pass to it. So an array would work significantly better, I think. Thanks!